# How to turn improve my hard-coded function so that it can easily change

Tags: python

Just want to start off and apologize if my question makes no sense. I didn't know how to word what I was trying to ask.

I am creating a connect 4 game for a project and right now it works fine.

But the problem is that the function has a lot of repeated coded and requires me to go back and expand the function if I want to add more players (it currently supports 3 but I want to keep the possibility of more than that open). Pretty much things are hard coded.

I was wondering if there was a better way to set up the code so it doesn't use repeated code and doesn't require me to go back and manually edit the entire function.

```
# Graphical representation of dropping the piece
def draw_drop_piece(event, turn):
    game_over = False

    if turn == 0:  # Checks to See if its Player 1 Turn
        posx = event.pos[0]
        col = int(math.floor(posx / SQUARE_SIZE))

        if is_valid(board, col):  # Checks Every Turn if Where the Player is Putting Their Piece is Valid
            row = next_open_row(board, col)
            drop_piece(board, row, col, 1)

            if winning_move(board, 1):  # Checks Every Turn if the Player Won
                label = FONT.render("PLAYER 1 WINS!", 1, RED)
                screen.blit(label, (40, 10))
                game_over = True

        else:
            label = FONT.render("Enter Valid Spot", 1, BLUE)
            screen.blit(label, (40, 10))
            game_over = None  # If the player made an invalid move it returns a none value

    elif turn == 1:
        posx = event.pos[0]
        col = int(math.floor(posx / SQUARE_SIZE))

        if is_valid(board, col):  # Checks Every Turn if Where the Player is Putting Their Piece is Valid
            row = next_open_row(board, col)
            drop_piece(board, row, col, 2)

            if winning_move(board, 2):  # Checks Every Turn if the Player Won
                label = FONT.render("PLAYER 2 WINS!", 1, YELLOW)
                screen.blit(label, (40, 10))
                game_over = True

        else:
            label = FONT.render("Enter Valid Spot", 1, BLUE)
            screen.blit(label, (40, 10))
            game_over = None  # If the player made an invalid move it returns a none value

    elif turn == 2:
        posx = event.pos[0]
        col = int(math.floor(posx / SQUARE_SIZE))

        if is_valid(board, col):  # Checks Every Turn if Where the Player is Putting Their Piece is Valid
            row = next_open_row(board, col)
            drop_piece(board, row, col, 3)

            if winning_move(board, 3):  # Checks Every Turn if the Player Won
                label = FONT.render("PLAYER 3 WINS!", 1, GREEN)
                screen.blit(label, (40, 10))
                game_over = True

        else:
            label = FONT.render("Enter Valid Spot", 1, BLUE)
            screen.blit(label, (40, 10))
            game_over = None  # If the player made an invalid move it returns a none value

    return game_over
```

Comment: **Moderator Note:** The mere existence of a site like Code Review does not make questions about improving code off-topic for Stack Overflow. If a question is sufficiently clear and narrowly-focused that it can be answered in Stack Overflow's Q&A format, then *it is on-topic for this site* and should not be migrated anywhere. Do not vote to close a question here because you think that it might be suitable for another site. We only close questions *here* because they are *off-topic here*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, you can avoid repeating the code!

```
# Graphical representation of dropping the piece
def draw_drop_piece(event, turn):
    game_over = False
    colors = (RED, YELLOW, GREEN) #usually a good way to avoid some repetitions is to store data in a container so you can easily call it in your code later
    if turn in (0,1,2):  # Checks to See if its Players Turn
        posx = event.pos[0]
        col = int(math.floor(posx / SQUARE_SIZE))

        if is_valid(board, col):  # Checks Every Turn if Where the Player is Putting Their Piece is Valid
            row = next_open_row(board, col)
            drop_piece(board, row, col, 1)

            if winning_move(board, turn+1):  # Checks Every Turn if the Player Won
                label = FONT.render("PLAYER {} WINS!".format(turn), 1, colors(turn)) #the format function allows to easily change a string in your code depending on values
                screen.blit(label, (40, 10))
                game_over = True

        else:
            label = FONT.render("Enter Valid Spot", 1, BLUE)
            screen.blit(label, (40, 10))
            game_over = None  # If the player made an invalid move it returns a none value
    return game_over
```